# Can I capture image and convert it to bitmap in android

Tags: android, android-intent, appcompatactivity

Can I capture image in android and convert it to bitmap without overriding `onActivityResult`

```
Intent takePicture = new Intent();
takePicture.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

Comment: Not really. `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` delivers its results via `onActivityResult()`, so that you know whether or not the user actually took the picture. What is the specific problem with overriding `onActivityResult()`?

Comment: I create BaseActivity and the other activities extends it.... I can only override the ،onActivityResult(), in the BaseActivity, and I cannot override it in the child activities

Comment: "I cannot override it in the child activities" -- why not?

Comment: it looks like that http://imgur.com/a/DG5p3

Comment: That is not how you override a method in Java.

Comment: How to override method in java...?!

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_overriding.htm. There are also many books and courses on Java that cover basic Java syntax such as this.